# reference request for proof of Gibbs phenomenon at jump discontinuities

Tags: reference-request, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Please suggest a reference for a proof of Gibbs phenomenon at jump discontinuities of a function.

Comment: Did you get something out of one of the answers below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Boggess and Narcowich's [book](http://books.google.com/books?id=paZVMSrlEw8C&printsec=frontcover) on wavelets and signal processing.

Answer (score 5):

You mean, a better reference than [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon#The_square_wave_example) one?